# Install PHP MSSQL Driver on Windows 2008 64bit IIS 7 - Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7, installation, windows-server-2008

maybe somebody is able to help with the following problem:

I have to install PHP 5.2 on Windows 2008 IIS with MSSQL Support but I'm unable to get MSSQL to work.

---

**Current situation**

- Windows 2008 Server 64bit
- IIS7
- PHP 5.2.17 installed with PHP Manager
- PHP works fine
- php_mssql doesn't (logs errors)

---

When I add the php_mssql.dll it won't work and it logs this error: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\PHP5.2\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0.

I know there is a problem with the ntwdblib.dll which is loaded internally from php_mssql.dll, but the file is in the PHP directory and I copied it everywhere: system32, php\ext etc but nothing works. That helps in previous installations every time in this case, but this is my first Windows 2008 64bit Installation, maybe there is a 64bit problem?

And I know I should use the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098) but that would lead me to other function calls (**sqlsrv_connect** instead of **mssql_connect**) and I have to run an old application which contains **mssql_** function calls on this server.

Comment: Is the web worker running in 32-bit mode?

Comment: How do I know that? Where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Argue with Whoru,

Our company Web system of 6 servers all run php with the MSSQL driver on IIS and its far more stable then LAMP in terms of hacking the server NTLM on a Domain Server is almost unbreakable  unlike SSH witch will let you retry to no end,

But you must use sqlsrv_connect as the php mssql_connect driver is dead wont work on SQL 2k5 or 2k8

We had to make the change on all of our servers sorry i could not give you better news

Comment: So the application has to be updated to sqlsrv_ functions, there is no other way. Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all why in the world you want to use PHP on Windows and that too using IIS and MSSQL?

Better solution for any of your problem would be **L** inux **A** pache **M** ySQL **P** HP

Comment: It's not **me** who wants that it's the **customer**. The question is about getting PHP/MSSQL/Win2008 to work.

Comment: But btw you are right, I would prefer a XAMPP installation but that isn't possible in the specific situation.